# No sound in 12.04 - excapt in wine

Tags: sound

I have a strange problem on my 12.04 LTS machine: 
Sound works OK in wine (using spotify for instance), but none of the native linux apps are able to produce any sound. 
I tested rythmbox and VLC player, and they both show the same behaviour; they seem to play ok (progress bar moving etc) but no sound can be heard anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

That line worked for me, it fixed my Minecraft sound problem without resetting anything.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

I put it at the end of

```
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check in "Sound Settings" that correct outputs are selected, sound cards are properly configured, and that applications playing sound are listed in the "Applications" tab. If you think everything there is correct, install PulseAudio Volume Control.

Check that the correct device is selected as "Fallback" (in the "Output devices" tab), and then that applications currently playing sound are playing it on the correct sound card (Note: If something has HDMI output, it's very likely to show up as a sound card). Finally, check if the applications themselves are not muted in PulseAudio Volume Control.

Comment: I googled around a bit and found a suggestion to add the line:
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
last in my /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file - and that seemed to do the trick; now the native linux apps play sounds ok (rythmbox + ubuntu system sounds at least).
But, now Wine has gone silent instead. Spotify (in wine), that used to work ok before, has now stopped working.

Comment: What sound card(s) do you have? Output of `aplay -l` would be nice.

Comment: aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Try that but without `options snd-hda-intel model=generic`. Also, you might want to try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Without options snd-hda-intel model=generic:
aplay -l:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC262 Analog [ALC262 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Googled your card, [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1542375) it says to add `options snd-hda-intel model=hp-rp5700` at the end of alsa-base.conf.

Comment: now i get sound in native linux apps as well as in wine apps.
It's not 100% stable. When alternating between playing sound in native linux apps and windows apps in wine I get a few no-sound scenarios, but sound is returned by re-starting the app in question. Thanks for your help!